# ASP .NET - RequiredFieldValidator creates space after textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DetailsView with a number of textboxes setup with RequiredFieldValidators.

The code for both is:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_time") %>'></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
         ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" 
         runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
         ErrorMessage="Please update date_time." 
         ValidationGroup="InsertDetailsView1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </InsertItemTemplate>
```

The problem is that the validation control is now creating a space (ie 
) between the textbox and the one below it.  How do I get rid of the space?  Is it a CSS thing?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set this property: `Display="Dynamic"`.

Comment: Thanks.

Note to self:

Add property to <asp:RequiredFieldValidator

Answer (score 6):

You can set Display="Dynamic" and the message will only show up when the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks.

Note to self: Add property to <asp:RequiredFieldValidator

Answer (score 0):

You could set Display="Dynamic", but you will still end up wrapping once the validation error is triggered if you don't leave a space big enough for the error message next to the control.

I usually put a red asterisk in for the error text, and then I put the actual error text in the ErrorMessage and ToolTip attributes, then display the long error message using a validation summary control.